# Sumifs outputting blank cells as zero

Tags: sumifs

I am trying to use a sumifs statement to sum a column over 2 criteria. The column I am summing over has blank cells. The sumifs statement returns a zero for these instances, and I want it to return blank. Some of the sums are actually equal to zero so I need to differentiate between the zeros and the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `if(isblank(cell), "", sumif())`

if the one of the cells is blank, it returns a blank
else, it will use the `sumif` formula

Comment: It won't use sumifs? I need to sum over multiple criteria

Comment: It seems like then it gives me blanks when the sum is actually zero, which I don't want